# What is the correct way to stream an index page to a client?

Tags: node.js

In most examples you find on the web, an `index.html` file is served like the following:

```
function serveIndexPage(response) {
  fs.readFile('__dirname + /public/index.html', function (err, data) {
      response.end(data);  
  });
};
```

This seems like a bad idea, as the whole file is read into memory and then send to the client. Is there some better way to do this? I know that libaries like Connect and Express provide such a functionality, but for my project, I'd like to use plain node.js.

**EDIT**

Also, you sometimes see `readFileSync` used, which is even worse IMHO.

Comment: You could use `fs.createReadStream(file).pipe(response)` which might improve performance, but if you're worried about this kind of performance, I suggest you serve static files using a static file server or a CDN.

Comment: Piping is the way to go. I don't agree with Linus tho. If you serve larger files you don't want to have everything in memory.

Comment: @Jan Would you mind providing an example?

Comment: Posted an example as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe your data through, so a simple static HTTP server looks like:

```
var Http = require('http'),
    Url = require('url'),
    Path = require('path'),
    Fs = require('fs');

Http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var path = Url.parse(req.url).pathname;
    var file = Path.join(process.cwd(), path);

    path.exists(filename, function(exists) {
        if(!exists) {
            res.writeHead(404);
            res.end();
        }

        res.writeHead(200, /* mime type */);

        var fileStream = Fs.createReadStream(filename);
        fileStream.pipe(res);
    });
}).listen(process.env.PORT || 1999);
```

---

The pipe'ing is shorthand for something like

```
var s = Fs.createReadStream(filename);

s.on('data', function (data) {
    res.write(data);
});
s.on('end', function() {
    res.end();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In theory you could read the file line by line response.write()'ing every line to the client.